# Load facebook content via ajax

Tags: php, facebook, jquery

Hello I have a problem with my website. I'm downloading my content via $.ajax from my php file. `(echo "My downloaded content <fb:like .....";)` In my content I have also facebook like buttons etc and the problem is that when I download content via Ajax all of facebook features are hidden (not working). When I had my content without ajax everything worked fine. I have my facebook api script in the bottom of my page.

here is my javascript and html code : http://jsfiddle.net/FWeUT/

and php is just echo.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Answer (score 0):

Facebook renders code-on-page only after its JS includes are loaded.  You could probably safely rewrite the Facebook JS include after your AJAX call.  Seeing that you're using jQuery, consider something like:

```
if (typeof (FB) != 'undefined') {
    FB.init({ status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
} else {
    $.getScript("http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1", function () {
        FB.init({ status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
    });
}
```

Comment: I added FB.XFBML.parse(); line at the end of my success callbacks of $.ajax and Facebook JS  include after my AJAX call like u said Saeven and still nothing :/ Mabe something is wrong with the datatype of ajax (html) or i added something in the wrong place. My fb include with appid etc I have just before the </body> tag, after that I have my script with ajax call and I tried adding after that the code u provided.

Comment: I think its working now ... I deleted FB.XFBML.parse(); from my success callback (because it didnt work) and at the end of my php script in which i added my site content to $result .= and et the end i had echo $result; I added also just before echo $return .= '<script>FB.XFBML.parse();</script>'; and it worked. I dont know why  earlier solution didn't but ... I'm happy :) thx u all :)