# Cross domain ajax by include

Tags: php, ajax, include, cross-domain, hybridauth

In `index.html` on my server, I use ajax to load the content of `file1.php` on my server.

In `file1.php`, the Facebook API is used through the HybridAuth Social Signon.

If I just run `file1.php`, it works fine. However, when running `index.html`, I run into the problem that the cross-domain AJAX request is not allowed, because the Facebook API is used.

I didn't think this was cross-domain, since the file I am loading is on the same server.
Is there a way to fix this, because most fixes I find around includes changing the response header, which I can't persuade Facebook to do.

Comment: maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240650/load-facebook-content-via-ajax

Comment: Maybe you’re better off using the JS SDK to make your API calls client-side in the first place …? (Depends on what exactly you are doing.) Anyway, your problem is not reproducible with the little info you have given, so please expand your explanation.

Comment: I think the problem is reproducible if you make a php file on your server that interacts with another server and then places an html file on your server which loads the content of your php file through AJAX. My question was also about whether this really is an AJAX cross-domain request, since the AJAX request is just for content of a file on the same server, which happens to interact with another server.